# How to represent this vector algebra for 2d point calculation using comma notation in a typical programming language?

Tags: javascript, math, vector, trigonometry, algebra

I reached out for help recently on math.stackexchange.com with a question about 2 dimensional algebra.  The answer was promptly provided but it's in mathematical notation unfamiliar to me and the person giving the answer has stopped responding to my questions.  While I am extremely grateful to BStar for providing this information, he/she has stopped replying both on the site and the chat, and doesn't seem interested in helping me understand it to the point that I could write programming code to calculate the desired point `P`.  I respect that, but it leaves me stuck for now.  Could someone help me convert this sequence of steps into a programming language such as Javascript? (I am actually working in PHP, but Javascript would be more convenient to represent in a runnable Snippet on stackoverflow .. I'm happy with any current language that I can translate into PHP).

The post is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110517/trig-101-calculate-coords-of-point-p-such-that-it-is-distance-n-from-line-ab-an/4110550?noredirect=1#comment8504010_4110550

The answer given is in Latex but here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

The latest description of the process by the author BStar: "Here is the process: First calculate cos B and use arccos to get B. Second calculate tanθ to get θ with arctan by using |BP| is the same from two triangles. Knowing these, we can get vectors BA’ and B’P, thus vectors OA and OP. We get θ to grt vector BA’ in this case, not the other way around. "

I can follow up until step (5) where the comma notation comes in, i.e. `k = (-xb, -yb)(xc - xb, yc - yb) / ac`.  This seems to make k a two dimensional vector but I don't think I ever worked with this notation.  Later, k is used in step `(6)` and `(6a)` to calculate theta, appearing both in the numerator and denominator of a fraction.  I have no idea how to expand this to get an actual value for theta.

(*Edit* Note: The author BStar assumed point A is at the origin, so `(xa, ya) = (0, 0)` but I cannot make that assumption in the real world.  Thus the vector `BA` in Step 1 is actually `(xa - xb, ya - yb)` and his formula for `k` shown above is actually `k = (xa - xb, ya - yb)(xc - xb, yc - yb) / ac`.  This expansion needs to be carried through the calculation but it's not a major change.)

If we were to frame this in Javascript, I could lay out a framework of what is known at the beginning of the calculation.  It's not productive to represent every single step of the mathematical proof given by BStar, but I'm not sure exactly what steps can be left as processes in the mathematical proof and what steps need expounding in code.

```js
/* Known points - A, B, C */
var xa = 10, ya = 10;
var xb = 100, yb = 500;
var xc = 700, yc = 400;

/* Known lengths m and n (distance perpendicularly from AB and AC) */
var m = 30;
var n = 50;

/* Point we want to calculate, P */
var px = 0, py = 0;

/* Calculation goes here - some Javascript notes:
 * var a = Math.sin(angInRadians);
 * var b = Math.asin(opposite / hypotenuse);
 * var c = Math.pow(number, 2); // square a number
 * var d = Math.sqrt(number);
 */

/* Print the result */
console.log('Result: P (' + px + ', ' + py + ')');
```

How would one express the maths from the diagram in the programming snippet above?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can get you to the angle of B but I'm not very good with math and get lost with all those variables. If you are stuck at figuring out the angle try this and see if it does what you want. It seems to do what step 5 is asking but double check my work.

```
let pointA = {x: 100, y: 0};
let pointB = {x: 20, y: 20};
let pointC = {x: 0, y: 100};

let distBA_x = pointB.x - pointA.x;
let distBA_y = pointB.y - pointA.y;
//let BA_a = Math.sqrt(distBA_x*distBA_x + distBA_y*distBA_y);

let distBC_x = pointB.x - pointC.x;
let distBC_y = pointB.y - pointC.y;
//let BC_c = Math.sqrt(distBC_x*distBC_x + distBC_y*distBC_y);

var angle = Math.atan2(distBA_x * distBC_y - distBA_y * distBC_x, distBA_x * distBC_x + distBA_y * distBC_y);
if(angle < 0) {angle = angle * -1;}
var degree_angle = angle * (180 / Math.PI);

console.log(degree_angle)
```

I've laid it out on a canvas so you can see it visually and change the parameters. Hope it helps. Here's the Codepen https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/RwKdpRw

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm swamped by another project and the solution BStar originally wrote (see Edits on the math.SO answer) works well enough.  Looks like you're onto something, I just need a few hours spare to work on this.  The boss has me trying to use the new eBay Media API which no PHP framework seems to support yet :/ I'll get back on this when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

`BA • BC` is a "dot product" between two vectors. The result is a single number: It's the sum of the products of vector components. If the vectors are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) the dot product is x1x2+y1y2.

Assuming you don't have a library for vector calculations and don't want to create one, the code for computing k would be:

```
k = (-xb*(xc - xb)-yb*(yc - yb)) / ac
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm swamped by another project and the solution BStar originally wrote (see Edits on the math.SO answer) works well enough.  Your comment on 'dot product' may be the key, it has been so long since I did vector maths I didn't even think of that process.  I will try to get back to this!